# Getting ASN1 bad tag error when trying to complete certificate request in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a multi-domain certificate I'm trying to install on IIS 7.0.

When I use the IIS manager to complete certificate request, I get the error:

There was an error while performing this operation.
Details:

CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::p_InstallResponse: ASN1 bad tag value met. 0x8009310b (ASN: 267)

One possible solution I found was to run certutil (after importing the cert via certmgr.msc):

certutil -repairstore my "certificate thumbprint"

But this gives me the error:

```
CertUtil: -repairstore command FAILED: 0x80090011 (-2146893807)
CertUtil: Object was not found.
```

I also tried importing the new certificate into IIS7, after converting it to a pfx file.  IIS takes it but I can't bind it.

The error I get when I try to bind it is :

There was an error while performing this operation.

Details : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the certificate have a private key?

Comment: Yes. I still have the certificate sitting in certificate enrollment requests. When I double click it, it says " you have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just getting a new certificate.

Here are a some links from my research:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/01/03/asn1-bad-tag-value-met-error-when-processing-a-certificate-request-in-iis-7.aspx

http://forums.iis.net/t/1147928.aspx